# Grub menu doesnt shows up after installing Ubuntu 19.04 alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grubrescue, grub-efi

I downloaded the iso file, made a bootable USB in UEFI with MBR, installed Ubuntu 19.04 with a swap area, home partition, root partition and efi partition. I also selected the newly made EFI partition to load in the section where it asks which or where the bootloader is installed (at the bottom in partitioning window of installation) while installing ubuntu. I did the installation but after I restart:
1. It ran into windows repair. 
2. It doesnt show the grub menu.

Before this, i installed with no home partition and all was good but now I am not aware of what is wrong with grub.

Beside that, in BIOS, I have disabled the legacy support and secure boot. ALso whenever I try to make Ubuntu my first partition while loading it doesn't happen in boot order priority.

I don't have much of linux knowledge and I install going through youtube videos. Last time I installed Ubuntu there was not any problem but it didn't have home partition.

So the solution I am looking for is to:
1. Show the grub menu at boot up
2. How does enabling/disabling legacy support affect the system and Ubuntu installation? 
3. Why this grub thing happens whenever I install any Linux distro alongside Windows?
4. How do I fix the missing grub menu ?

Comment: What brand/model system? If Windows is UEFI, you want Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode also. And then you never want to turn on Legacy/BIOS/CSM boot mode. You separately have to boot installer only in UEFI boot mode.May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: you don't want MBR you want GPT. use https://rufus.ie/ to create your ubuntu usb and pick GPT, run the installer again. Also, grub isn't able to write because you need to open an admin CMD in your windows and type `powercfg -h off` befoehand and then you can reboot to your installer usb. this prevents windows from hard-locking the Hard Drives on shutdown/reboot.